# socket.io issues. Can't figure out why its not persisently sending data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I think something in my configuration isn't set up correctly. It only sends data when i restart my server and sometimes that doesn't always send the data. My stack is node.js with express and react. Here is my app.js file

```
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const options = {
  cors: true,
  origins: ['http://127.0.0.1:3000'],
  'force new connection': true,
};
const io = require('socket.io')(server, options);


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('connecting..', socket.id);

  socket.on('chat', (chat) => {
    console.log(chat);
    if (chat) {
      io.sockets.emit('chat', chat);
    }
  });

  socket.on('remove', (socket) => {
    console.log('user disconnected!');
  });
});

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('listening on port ' + port);
  db.sync({
    // force: true,
    logging: false,
  });
});
```

and client side in app.js i set the socket and io like this

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
const ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:4000';
var socket = io(ENDPOINT, { forceNew: true });
```

and pass it to my component

```
 <Chatroom
            user={user}
            getAllMessages={getAllMessages}
            setGetAllMessages={setGetAllMessages}
            socket={socket}
            io={io}
          />
```

```
const Chatroom = ({ user, getAllMessages, setGetAllMessages, socket, io }) => {
  const [getMessages, setGetMessages] = useState();
  const [userMessage, setUserMessage] = useState('');
  const [getAllUsers, setGetAllUsers] = useState();
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);
  const [personalMessage, setMessage] = useState();
  const [getSocket, setSocket] = useState(socket);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('connected.');
    });

    socket.emit('chat', personalMessage);

    return () => {
      socket.emit('remove', () => {
        socket.disconnect();
      });
    };
  }, [socket, getSocket]);
```

Comment: You are only sending one `socket.emit('chat', personalMessage);`. How are you expecting it to send data many times? What logs are you expecting?

Comment: I guess my question would be. How do I get socket.emit to fire every time a user sends a chat message

Comment: You should make a `click` /`enter` event handler in your component and emit from there instead of the `useEffect`